# How to extract the last character of a string of unknown length?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a function that takes stringA and stringB as parameters and compares the first character of stringB with the last character of StringA. If they are equal, then the function returns `true`, else `false` is returned.

I have nearly the whole function ready, however I can't find a way to take the last character of stringA because its length is unknown. I checked the documentation and I found nothing. Any suggestions?

```
  (cond
    [(string=? (substring stringA ???) (substring stringB 0 2))"True"]
    [else "False"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last character position of a string using `string-length` (or rather one less than):

```
(string-ref str (sub1 (string-length str)))
```

Note that a *character* is different from a *string of length 1*. Thus the correct way to extract a character is with `string-ref` or the like, rather than `substring`.

Comment: Can you explain where the sub1 comes from? I tried doing this and it seems like the right place to start except for the sub1, whose purpose is not yet clear to me. Thanks

Comment: The `sub1` comes from using zero-based indexing. In one-based indexing, the indices go from `1` to `n` where `n` is the length, but in zero-based indexing, they go from `0` to `n-1`, or `(sub1 n)`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Chris answered your question. Just a reminder, to use the string-ref, which returns a character, you should use the comparison function char=? (or equal?).

I'd like to add another solution which I find more elaborate, but requires to download a collection from the planet racket (after installing package collections). Using the collections package, you can use the same function with any collection rather then just strings, using the (last ..) and (first ..) functions of the module.

```
(require data/collection)

(let ([stringA "abcd"]
      [stringB "dcba"])
  (cond
    [(equal? (last stringA)
             (first stringB)) "True"]
    [else "False"]))
```

Comment: You can also use `eqv?` to compare characters. But for good readability, I do prefer `char=?` unless there's a good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `SRFI-13` function `string-take-right`, which returns the last `n` characters of the argument string as a string.

Answer (score -1):

every language has a length function for a string. in Racket I found this :

[https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def.*%28%28quote.*~23~25kernel%29._string-length%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-length%29%29)

there is this : string-length str

so just run that it will give you the length and then you can extract the last character